# Не работатет замена текста {{ header }} когда захожу на главную страницу

Tags: php, .htaccess, маршрутизация, xampp, route

index.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$route0 = '/posts/(?<catSlug>[a-z0-9_-]+)/(?<pageSlug>[a-z0-9_-]+)';
$route1 = '/registration';
$route2 = '/login';
$route3 = '/posts';
$route4 = '/profile'; 
$route5 = '/about';
$route6 = '/';



if(preg_match("#$route0#", $url, $params)) {
    $page = include 'view/page/posts2.php';
} 
elseif(preg_match("#$route1#", $url, $params)) {
    $page = include 'view/page/registration.php';
}
elseif(preg_match("#$route2#", $url, $params)) {
    $page = include 'view/page/login.php';
}
elseif(preg_match("#$route3#", $url, $params)) {
    $page = include 'view/page/posts.php';
}
elseif(preg_match("#$route4#", $url, $params)) {
    $page = include 'view/page/profile.php';
}
elseif(preg_match("#$route5#", $url, $params)) {
    $page = include 'view/page/about.php';
}
elseif(preg_match("#$route6#", $url, $params)) {
    $page = include 'view/page/main.php';
}

$layout = file_get_contents('view/layout.php');

// $layout = str_replace('{{ title }}', $page['title'], $layout);

$layout = str_replace('#{{ header }}#', $page['WHY'], $layout);

// $layout = str_replace('#{{ content }}#', $content, $layout);
// $layout = str_replace('#{{ footer }}#', $footer, $layout);
var_dump($layout);

// include 'view/page/main.php';
```

main.php:

```
<?php
$page = [];
$page['WHY'] = '
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pofile</a></li>
</ul>';
return $page;
```

layout.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="view/html_form.png" type="image/png">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
<header align="center">
    {{ header }}
</header>
<main>
    {{ content }}
</main>
<footer>
    {{ footer }}
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: давайте исходить из того, что str_replace в php рабочий. Мы не знаем, что у вас в layout и по какой ветке ifов вы пришли. Поэтому, выводите перед str_replace layout  и page. Смотрите, и я думаю, видите, что не так

Comment: может замена идет только по sql?

Comment: Здесь нет никакого sql.

Comment: Ты видишь в `layout.php` текст `#{{ header }}#`?

Comment: да вижу в точ точ такой

Comment: А я вот вижу в тексте вопроса `{{ header }}`. А `{{ header }}` это не `#{{ header }}#`.

Comment: это же ограничители

Comment: в регулярных выражениях

Comment: оставь ответ в ответнике, я повышу тебе социальный рейтинг